# MongoDB group a document by id showing all values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this document format

[image]

And I have some documents with the same ID, but different contents, so I want to group them by id and push all the contents into an array

I tried this

```
$group : { "_id": "$_id",  "contents": { $push: "$contents" } }
```

but its only bringing me two fields (_id and contents)

[image]

How do I need to make the query to group the contents in an array and still show me all the other fields of the same id?

Comment: I'm curious... How do you get  `_id` multiple times if they are by default [unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-_id-index)? How can the database has documents with same _id?

Comment: Because in the aggregate query I did ```$unwind : "$contents"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
db.foo.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "contents": { $push: "$contents" },
                users: { $first: "$users" },
                owners: { $first: "$owners" },
                name: { $first: "$name" },
                category: { $first: "$category" },
                course: { $first: "$course" },
                // and remaining fields
            }
        }
    ])
```